# coffeescript autogenerated namespace causes reference error jasmine test

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine

I try to write some simple tests in Coffeescript and Jasmine.

```
# greet.coffee    
greet = (message, person) ->
  "#{message}, #{person}!"
```

and here my Jasmine Spec File:

```
# greetSpec.coffee
describe 'greet', ->

  it 'should greet with message and name', ->
    result =  greet 'Hello', 'John'
    expect(result).toBe 'Hello, John!'
```

When i start SpecRunner in Jasmine i get: 
**ReferenceError: greet is not defined**

I guess it has something to do with the namespace autogenerated by coffeescript and therefor is the greet function not visible from the Spec file. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, could solve it with a simple global variable (not sure if that's a good way, though):

greet.coffee:

```
@greet = (message, person) ->
  "#{message}, #{person}!"
```

greetSpec.coffee:

```
describe 'greet', ->

  it 'should greet with message and name', ->
    result =  greet 'Hello', 'John'
    expect(result).toBe 'Hello, John!'
```